# how to create circular loop to a view pager without backtracking previous elements

Tags: android, android-viewpager, infinite-scroll, viewpagerindicator, circular-list

I need to design a ViewPager from an array of string resources and show circular page indicator. Now i want to set first item when user swipe left from last item and set last item when swipe right from first item. after going through many solutions it is backtracking the whole path while swiping left from last item. Any way to do it without backtracking. i want to set to first item smoothly without traversing the whole path again.

below is the code i have used.

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mAdapter = new PromoPagerAdapter(getActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)      view.findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
    circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);



@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    mCurrentPosition = position;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    int currentPage = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    if (currentPage == mAdapter.getCount()-1 || currentPage == 0) {
        previousState = mCurrentPosition;
        mCurrentPosition = state;
        if (previousState == 1 && mCurrentPosition == 0) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage == 0 ? mAdapter.getCount()-1 : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since Stackoverflow is a programming website, we work in code. Please post relevant code as to what you have tried so far, as we are unable to do it for you. Please refer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

This library do what you want:
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider